# Permission denied android studio launch, what to do?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions

I'm trying to launch installed android studio on 
Macos high sierra 10.12.
Possibly error is of permission issue
How to fix that? I need AS for React Native app

actual error:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7muNp.jpg)

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:225)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.lambda$initApplication$0(IdeaApplication.java:78)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:367)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:259)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:506)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$9(ApplicationImpl.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:453)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:391)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:218)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.picocontainer.defaults.PicoInvocationTargetInitializationException: InvocationTargetException: java.io.FileNotFoundException /Users/dickens/.android/analytics.settings (Permission denied)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:106)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:76)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:59)
```

Comment: Can you run it as administrator?

Comment: Also check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQP_R7bBS28) since I have no idea how to mess with Hackintosh.

Comment: Yes, if I run this with root I can open Android Studio, however it messes everything, because it download the AVD to /root/ user still the app exist at my user

Comment: Sorry. Can you clarify the problem? I'm not familiar with those things..

Comment: The last error in the stacktrace says there is a missing file. Could you confirm if the file **analytics.settings** is present in the folder **/Users/dickens/.android**?

Comment: I don't use Android Studio but VS, sorry..

Comment: Can't you add an option to run this program as administrator each time it's executed?

Comment: Thanks for your help, problem was solved. Posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that I didn't have permission for my /Users/[username]/.android/ folder. /.android/ owner was root.
To change this execute this command in terminal to move to .android folder

```
cd /Users/[username]/.android/
```

Then to see who is the owner of the files

```
ls -l
```

Finally, set the permission of the folder to your user

```
sudo chown -R [username] /Users/[username]/.android/
```

Comment: Glad to hear. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_S_CChgPTg) tutorial is for you.